# How to exclude resources from android shrinkResources?

Tags: android, gradle

How can I exclude all `/res/raw/*.wav` files from shrinking?

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Comment: Ok, I was searching for keyword "exclude", but the correct term seems to be "keep or discard".

Comment: just out of curiosity, why do you want to prevent shrink for wav file?

Comment: Because I'm getting an IOException if I shrink them, when loading in `MediaPlayer`. I'm not referencing the files with `R.raw.name`, but dynamically getting their resid by reflection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/res/raw/keep.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           tools:keep="*.wav"/>
```

Comment: Do not specify extension, only resource name!

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar issue with two wav files - `bell.wav` and `beep.wav` in the `res/raw/` folder. membersounds's [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45435370/4171025) pointed the right direction, but did not solve the issue - this is the `/res/raw/keep.xml` that worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           tools:keep="@raw/bell,@raw/beep"/>
```